# ngx-emoji mart - Type 'string' is not assignable error

Tags: angular, typescript, string

I was working on a project with `@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart` package. When I used that package in Stackblitz it worked fine, but when I copy-pasted that code in my local system it gave me this error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"" | "apple" | "google" | "twitter" | "facebook"'.

16         set="{{ set }}"
```

This is the Stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q9fwpz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared-component%2Fdialog-box%2Fdialog.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftab1%2Ftab1.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftab1%2Ftab1.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Finfo.ts,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftab1%2Ftab1.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared-component%2Fdialog-box%2Fdialog-box.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared-component%2Fdialog-box%2Fdialog-box.component.html).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you have applied strict checking in your Angular project.

From your StackBlitz link, I am able to re-create the error by enabling the below settings in *tsconfig.json*.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "strict": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

[Reproduce Error Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9rmzr9?file=src/app/shared-component/dialog-box/dialog-box.component.html)

---

**Issue**

According to [`<emoji-mart>` Component](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-emoji-mart/blob/68438a341f8e7b5f2782025239b1cd33669aecec/src/lib/picker/picker.component.ts#L85),

```js
@Input() set: Emoji['set'] = 'apple';
```

The `set` input property is expected to receive the value with the `Emoji['set']` type.

For the available options of `set`, you may read the [`Emoji` interface](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-emoji-mart/blob/68438a341f8e7b5f2782025239b1cd33669aecec/src/lib/picker/ngx-emoji/emoji.component.ts#L21).

```js
set: 'apple' | 'google' | 'twitter' | 'facebook' | '';
```

---

**Solution**

Apply the property binding `[set]="set"`.

> HTML

```
<emoji-mart
    class="emoji-mart"
    [set]="set"
    *ngIf="showEmojiPicker"
    (emojiSelect)="addEmoji($event)"
    title="Pick your emoji…"
  ></emoji-mart>
```

> Component

Declare the `set` property with `Emoji['set']` type.

```js
import { Emoji } from '@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/ngx-emoji';

set: Emoji['set'] = 'twitter';
```

[Demo Solution @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbpzzu?file=src/app/shared-component/dialog-box/dialog-box.component.html)